# Populate html table with http API request in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, servlets, meteor

I have a table

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Year</th>
   <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1990</td>
   <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  ...
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and I want to make a GET request to World Bank API to fill out the values in this table.

My GET request is in a Meteor method

```
Meteor.methods({
  getData: function () {
    try {
      const url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/br/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD?date=1990:2000&format=json';
      const request = HTTP.get(url);
      return request;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return false;
    }
  },
});
```

and I call my method from the client with

```
Meteor.call('getData', function(error, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

So I get the values in the console, but I want to replace `-` in the html table with the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the {{#each}} block helper to loop through the array. E.g.

```
<tbody>
 {{#each getData}}
 <tr>
  <td>{{date}}</td>
  <td>{{value}}</td>
 </tr>
 {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Where `getData` is a template helper that fetches the data. However, because the data you're getting is async, you cannot simply do `Meteor.call()` directly in the helper.

One way to solve this is with a session variable ('meteor add session' to install the package).

First, you'd fetch the data when creating the template and set it to a session variable:

```
Template.your_template.onCreated(function() {
    Meteor.call('getData', function(error, result) {
        // result.data[1] is the array of objects with the data
        Session.set('bankData', result.data[1]);
    });
});
```

Then, use a template helper to pass the data to template:

```
Template.your_template.helpers({
    getData: function(){        
        return Session.get('bankData');
    }
});
```